# nHibernate Eager Loading at runtime

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, ncommon

We're using NCommon's UnitOfWorkScope which wraps nHibernate ISession functionality. Our goal is to eager-load complex properties on demand vs. always eagerly loading them via configuration. The idea is that a given service that retrieves an entity can be customized a bit by the calling code - sometimes we want only the parent entity to be hydrated, other times we may want the complex child properties hydrated, too.

To accomplish this, we're doing the following:

```
  var iSession = unitOfWorkScope.CurrentUnitOfWork<NHUnitOfWork>().GetSession<ParentEntity>();

  iSession.CreateCriteria<ParentEntity>().SetFetchMode("Children", FetchMode.Eager);
```

Once that's setup on the session, we use NCommon's IRepository functionality to retrieve the entities:

```
  var parent = parentRepository.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 123);
```

However, when we check the parent.Children collection we get:

```
  NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag<ChildEntity>
```

... which tells me the Eager-loading did not occur. When we modify the NH mapping to always force an eager load, then we see the children correctly.

Can anyone shed light on this? I assume we're missing something since the FetchMode.Eager is ignored.

Comment: Sorry, why are you assuming eager loading did not occur? That is the class NHibernate uses for bags.

Comment: Because the Children property isn't populated. When we configure Eager loading via the config we always get a populated Children collection, but when we try to do it at runtime via FetchMode on the ISession, we get the PersistentGenericBag which, when accessed, throws a LazyInitializationException.

Comment: It appears that NH's Session.Query<T>() doesn't respect criteria already created on the Session via calls to CreateCriteria(). I thought calls to that would be respected when Query() is called but apparently not... ???

Comment: Why aren't you keeping the session open for the whole business transaction? Is there a network boundary between the calling code and your repository? If so, you should use dto's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution, found here:

http://slynetblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/in-spite-of-common-now-approach-of.html

Comment: In the end, we decided against an EagerFetch solution although it worked. We simplified the approach by allowing LazyLoading and moving UnitOfWorkScope's up from the service layer to the business layer. Also - if you're using NServiceBus, don't forget that it will create an ambient transaction for you with IsolationLevel.Serializable which won't work if you want db operations to use ReadCommitted. You must configure NSB to use ReadCommitted and then everything is happy.